# How to check if user has a role that allows to access the site?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 4 tables with the following information:

```
users          | roles     | users_roles  | page_access
---------------+-----------+--------------+--------------
user_id        | role_id   | user_role_id | ID
first_name     | role_name | user_id      | Page
last_name      |           | role_id      | Page_Groups
email          |           |              |
password       |           |              |
admin_approved |           |              |
```

I need to get the roles for the signed-in user (roles.role_name) and compare those with the values from page_access.Page_Groups. This is to check if the user has permission to access the site or not.

I believe I am making it more difficult than it seems. I want to fix the hardcoded solution that I have implemented.

```
TABLE: roles

role_id        | role_name
---------------+------------
1              | Admin
2              | Subscriber
3              | Viewer
4              | UAS Pilot

TABLE: page_access

ID             | Page                    | Page_Groups
---------------+-------------------------+------------------
1              | data_visualization      | Admin
2              | page_access             | Admin
3              | uas_data_admin          | Admin;Subscriber
4              | visualization_generator | Admin
```

```
<?php
require_once("Resources/PHP/SetDBConnection.php");
$con = SetDBConnection();

session_start();

$_VERIFY = $_SESSION['email'];

// SELECT USING EMAIL TO GET THE role_id
$sql = "select role_id from users_roles, users where  users_roles.user_id = users.user_id and email = '".$_VERIFY."' ORDER BY role_id ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


if(mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to database server: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}

else
{
    $userName = $_SESSION["email"];

    $roles = $row["role_id"];

    if ($roles == 1)
        $groups = 'Admin';// Need to fix hardcoding. Get values from table // HAS TO BE AN ARRAY

    unset($_SESSION["page"]);

    if (!$roles){
        $_SESSION["page"] =  "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
        header("Location: http://mainpage");
        exit();
    } else  {
        $pageName = basename(__DIR__);
        if ($pageName == "V2"){
            $pageName = basename(realpath(__DIR__ . "/.."));
        }

        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM page_access WHERE Page = '$pageName'";
        $allowedGroups = array();
        if ($result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql1)){
            if ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
                $allowedGroups = explode(";", $row1["Page_Groups"]);
                //print_r($allowedGroups); // [0] => Admin [1] => Subscriber
                $accessGroupsStr = $row1["Page_Groups"];
                //_log($accessGroupsStr);// Admin;Subscriber
            }
        }

        $groups_array = array("Admin", "Subscriber"); // Need to fix hardcoding. Get values from table // HAS TO BE AN ARRAY
        $intersect = array_intersect($groups_array,$allowedGroups);// input has two be 2 arrays

        if (sizeof($intersect) > 0){// if match found
            ?>

            <!DOCTYPE>
            <html lang="html">

            <head>
            </head>

            <body>
            </body>
            </html>

            <?php
        } else {
            $memberOf = (implode("; ", $groups));
            ?>

            <!DOCTYPE>
            <html lang="html">
            <head>
                <title><?php echo $page; ?></title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <p>Hello, <?php echo $userName; ?>!</p>
            <p>You do not currently have permission to access this page</p>
            <p>Please contact admin at <a href="mailto:example@example.edu">example@example.edu</a></p>
            </body>
            </html>

            <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question - is this working but you're looking for a way to simplify it? Is it not working how you want? Can you explain what is happening compared to what you're expecting to happen? Also, trimming this down to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help us help you.

Comment: So effectively you want all of the `roles` associated with the user in text form in an array?

Comment: @Steven yes, that is correct

Comment: Do you not store the `user_id` as a variable in `$_SESSION`?

Comment: I do, but the user_id from the users table comes from auto_increment

Comment: That doesn't matter so long as it acts as a `foreign key` in `users_roles`

Comment: Yes, it acts as a foreign key in users_roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you store the logged on `user_id` as a variable in `$_SESSION` there's no need to go anywhere near the `users` table.

This should do the trick:

**mysqli**

```
// SELECT the role_name for each users_roles for the logged on user
// ? is a place holder for our parameter `user_id`
$sql = "
    SELECT r.role_name FROM users_roles AS ur
        JOIN roles AS r ON r.role_id = ur.role_id
    WHERE u.user_id = ?
";

$query = $mysqli->prepare($sql);                // Prepare the query
$query->bind_param("i", $_SESSION["user_id"]);  // Bind the parameter (wherever you store user_id in $_SESSION)
$query->execute();                              // Run the query
$query->store_result();                         // Store the result
$query->bind_result($role_name);                // Bind the result to a variable

$user_role_array = [];                          // Initialise the user roles array
while($query->fetch()){                         // Loop returned records
    $user_role_array[] = $role_name;            // Add user role to array
}

// Should output something like: ["Admin", "Subscriber"]
```

**PDO**

```
// SELECT the role_name for each users_roles for the logged on user
// ? is a place holder for our parameter `user_id`
$sql = "
    SELECT r.role_name FROM users_roles AS ur
        JOIN roles AS r ON r.role_id = ur.role_id
    WHERE u.user_id = ?
";

$query = $PDO->prepare($sql);                // Prepare the query
$query->execute([$_SESSION["user_id"]]);     // Run the query and bind parameter

// Fetch each record as a record in an array
$user_role_array = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);


// Should output something like: ["Admin", "Subscriber"]


// Shortened code credit goes to @Dharman for use of `fetchAll`
```

Comment: With PDO you can simply do `$user_role_array = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);` without the loop